# Multiple shorter questions or one more complex question?

Tags: discussion

If a questions could be refactored into multiple smaller questions, is it best to do so, potentially cross-linking the questions, or is it best to ask a broader question that would require longer, more complex answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically it is better to ask very specific questions that can be completely and thoroughly answered in the space of one post. If you are asking multi-part questions (requiring multi-part answers), it can become difficult to know what folks are actually voting on… and if the post (in its entirely) is what is being voted to the top. Break it out when you can.

Also, cross-linking questions is only necessary if you feel it provides *important* context and background. Folks finding your question through search just want their answer without having to read a lot of extraneous information, so generally you should at least *try* to make every question/answer stand on its own merits.